# python imaging library truncated image problem

Tags: python, image-preprocessing

I'm working with PIL in python to load and resize a large number of images, to feed to a CNN. But during the process of loading this error happens:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9e7a5298cd3e> in <module>
      3 dog_names = ip.labels("dogImages/train")
      4 
----> 5 trn_data, trn_targets = ip.data_loader('dogImages/train', (224, 224))
      6 val_data, val_targets = ip.data_loader('dogImages/valid', (224, 224))
      7 tst_data, tst_targets = ip.data_loader('dogImages/test', (224, 224))

...my address...\libs\img_preprocessing.py in data_loader(path, size)
     48             cat_target.append([1 if pre_label(im)==label else 0 for label in labels(total)])
     49             img = Image.open(im)
---> 50             img = Image.Image.resize(img, size=size)
     51             img = np.array(img)
     52             arr.append(img)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in resize(self, size, resample, box, reducing_gap)
   1922             return im.convert(self.mode)
   1923 
-> 1924         self.load()
   1925 
   1926         if reducing_gap is not None and resample != NEAREST:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py in load(self)
    247                                     break
    248                                 else:
--> 249                                     raise OSError(
    250                                         "image file is truncated "
    251                                         f"({len(b)} bytes not processed)"

OSError: image file is truncated (150 bytes not processed)
```

I've seen some suggestions about adding this code:

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = False
```

But I think it allows defective data to enter our model. I don't want that. I want to skip corrupted images without crashing the program, and load all the rest of the images, but i can't figure it out.
The code I use is this:

```
def data_loader(path, size):
    '''
    loading image data
    parameters:
        path => image directory path
        size => output size in tuple
    '''
    total = glob(path + "/*")
    arr = []
    for _dir in total:
        for im in glob(_dir+"/*"):
            img = Image.open(im)
            img = Image.Image.resize(img, size=size)
            img = np.array(img)
            arr.append(img)
    return np.array(arr)
```

Comment: If you are actually getting an error, can't you protect your load/resizing pipeline usin a try/except? You probably should return a list of the files that were loaded.

Comment: @nonDucor yes i was thinking about that. now I know the error is actually comes from resize method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error is occurring when you attempt to resize, enclose that line in a `try`/`except`. When you get the error, `continue` skips the rest of the current iteration and continues on with the next image file.

```
from glob import glob

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_data(path, size):
    '''
    loading image data
    parameters:
        path => image directory path
        size => output size in tuple
    '''
    total = glob(path + "/*")
    images = []
    for subdir in total:
        for im in glob(subddir + "/*"):
            img = Image.open(im)
            try:
                img = img.resize(size)
            except OSError:
                continue
            img = np.array(img)
            images.append(img)
    return np.array(images)
```

Some other minor things I changed:

- `data_loader` sounds more like a class than a function. I recommend verbs for functions, or at least not nouns that sound like they perform actions.
- As a variable name, `arr` is both generic (what's in it?) and misleading (it's a list, not an array).
- Variables starting in `_` are, by convention, usually used for "private" attributes.
- `img.resize(size)` is just a simpler way of calling the `resize` method.